# How to change segue kind programmatically?

Tags: swift, segue

How would I programmatically change the kind of a segue that was created in storyboard?

I want to change the segue kind depending on the device type. For `.phone` the storyboard segue of kind "show" (push) should be executed. For `.pad` I want to change the segue kind to "modal".

Would I do that in the `prepareForSegue` or do I have to stop the segue from being executed in `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` and manually perform a modal segue?

**EDIT:** This question is focusing on changing the segue type, not on how to identify the device type.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
enum UIUserInterfaceIdiom : Int {
    case Unspecified
    case Phone // iPhone and iPod touch style UI
    case Pad // iPad style UI
}
```

and in `viewDidLoad()`

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vc2") as! myViewController

    switch UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom {

    case .Phone:
      self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        break

    case .Pad:
      self.showViewController(vc, sender: nil)
        break
    case .Unspecified:
        // Do something
        break
    default:
       // Do something
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Led, I knew how to identify the device type. I would like to know how to change the segue. Maybe that was not clear in my post, I will update it.

Comment: @Manuel You might be interested in presentViewController() and  showViewController() functions